# After opening kml files in vba the fonts are strange in Google Earth

Tags: vba, ms-access, fonts, kml, google-earth

I wrote a procedure to create kml file from a record in Access table to go for a definite placemark in Google Earth. It does the job well, but it read the name in strange font when it is in Arabic. I stated the problem, it is when the file is opened by the statement open to change the data. How to make kml file with Arabic fonts.